# atheros ar8161 not recognized

Tags: networking

Apparently I am not the only one with this problem, this was my solution, but it did not work, of course:

I downloaded the tar from another computer. I found the file of the atheros driver that I needed which is apparently atl1c, put that file on my ubuntu desktop and ran the following in the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
atl1c
make
sudo make install
```

Isn't there a simple code I could use once I have the atl1c folder on the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
wget -O- http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-11-13-pc.tar.bz2 | tar -xj

cd compat-wireless-2012-11-13-pc
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
```

After reboot, you can use your Atheros card.

If you downloaded [driver package](http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-11-13-pc.tar.bz2) on your desktop:
Open a terminal:

```
cd Desktop
tar -xj compat-wireless-2012-11-13.tar.gz
cd compat-wireless-2012-11-13-pc
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: But now I am getting permission denied messages. I am given to understand that there is some sort of chmod command that must be employed.<div class="post-text"> <pre><code>chmod 777 compat-wireless-2012-11-13-pc</pre></code>
</div> maybe?

Comment: Except "cd Desktop" command, try other commands with sudo.

Comment: OK, actually the chmod 777 strategy worked. A long process started with driver-select. But at the end I get a bunch of error messages. Error 1 and error 2