# Working Network Card NOT Recognized by Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, networking

I've got Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal), Linix version 3.9.0-999 generic.  The box is HP dual boot with Win 7.  I've got a gigabit home LAN and the box is fine with that in Win 7.  Ethernet adapter MAC 78 E3 B5 AE B9 01.  However on the Ubuntu side lspci gives me "Ethernet Controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (Rev 8)".  However ifconfig give me the loopback and eth0 MAC address 44 6D 57 F8 67 0A and zip else.  On the Ubuntu side I'm on the home LAN wireless but Ubuntu won't find and use the gigabit card that Win 7 uses happily and lspci tells me is physically there.

Can anyone help?  I need to get Ubuntu to find and use a perfectly functional gigabit network "card".

Answer (score 0):

There are some suggestions for that parcticular card [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216975/atheros-ar8161-not-recognized) though it is unclear if the solution offered fully solved the problem.

You can also search for "Atheros" and browse the list of issues reported. Most seem to center on wifi, but there may be a solution within those questions.